# Display the meta data of a page on the page itself

Tags: javascript, page-layout

I want to display the page metadata (e.g status) of an aspx-page on the site itself. The sites are located in the default site pages library.

library:

Name:page1 Status:draft

Name:page2 Status: approved

On the aspx-page1 I want to display the its status "draft", on page2 the status "approved" and so on.

What is the best way to do it?